# Infinite Scroll TableView Using FetchLimit And Core Data in IOS

Tags: ios, tableview, infinite-scroll, nsfetchrequest

I have thousands of rows of Data in Core Data. Doing a fetch that large slows down the UX noticeably. Since I let the user view the data in various ways, reloads are common and reloading the FRC can be painful. Accordingly, I have been putting a FetchLimit in my Fetch of say 50.  50 is great for speed, but only pulls a fraction of the rows so older data is simply not accessible.

I would like to implement an infinite scroll so fresh rows are loaded when the user hits the bottom of the TableView.  I can trigger the reload using any of several  delegate methods such as:

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [tableView numberOfSections] - 1;
        NSInteger lastRowIndex = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
        if ((indexPath.section == lastSectionIndex) && (indexPath.row == lastRowIndex)) {
            // This is the last cell
            [self getMore];
        }
    }
```

My problem is what to use for Get More.  The following works but seems clumsy as you need to reload all the earlier cells and it gets difficult to keep track of where you are in the fetchLimit.  Is there a more efficient way to accomplish an infinite scroll?

```
   - (void)getMore {
        [self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchLimit:newFetchLimit];
       self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
        NSError *error;
        if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
            // Update to handle the error appropriately.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your getMore function you can use the [fetchOffset](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506770-fetchoffset) property in combination with fetchLimit so you can you can create a subrange of an arbitrary result set and avoid reloading all your cell contents again.

```
[fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest setFetchOffset: newFetchOffset];
```

Where `newFetchOffset` is going to start at 0 and on your second request you need to set it with 50 so you can get the next 50th values.